# URL Breaks in prestashop1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I downloaded the theme. The category is added as the menu in navigation bar.

When I click on menu. It takes The requested URL ---- was not found on this server. How to fix this.. I dont know where the htaccess file in prestashop. Please guide me to fix this. Thanks in advance

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSFzr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check  settings in Back Office

http://doc.prestashop.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/20578464

Answer (score 0):

Your site is within a repeat loop and can not help you without a detailed check of the codes and without access to the management section.

It's better to get help from a PrestaShop expert.

Another solution is to remove the newly installed modules one by one to determine which module cause the problem.

Comment: vérifier les parametres d'ajout des categories et des sous categories de menu    
 https://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-how-to-add-custom-links-to-categories-menu.html